# Not getting an option for Javascript VM and Web 3 provider in remix ide environment?

Tags: remix

Remix IDE Environment

Javascript VM and Web 3 provider option in remix ide environment (browser version) are missing

I tried to explore in youtube and google however I didn't got any answer

Answer (score 6):

You should use Remix VM (London) as it's the same and was previously called as Javascript VM.

Now, for Injected web3 use Injected Provider - Metamask as it's the most common provider.

You can refer to the documentation as well for more updated information: https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to double check if either correctly installed or not

Comment: I am using broswer version https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js